# Firefox Extension change data folder location

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Here at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data), I found out that if I want to load data like images, custom HTML views or videos, I have to store them in top-level project folder called `data`.

However, that completely breaks my project skeleton.

My goal is to create a "homepage" for my extension that would open whenever a user clicks my extension's toolbar icon. My "homepage" document is currently stored in `data/view/main.html`. Is there any way to make Firefox accept locations like `src/view/main.html`?